# Error connecting to DB2 with python and sqlalchemy - Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, db2

I'm trying to connect to an IBM DB2 database using SQLAlchemy connection format but it keeps failing to connect.

I am using these libraries:

```
!pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.9
!pip install ibm_db_sa
!pip install --force-reinstall ibm_db_sa ibm_db
```

Loading the connector:

```
%load_ext sql
```

My connection string:

```
%sql ibm_db_sa://jqg6xxxx:r9C98t4TY81xxxxx@fbd88901-ebdb-4a4f-a32e-9822b9fb237b.c1ogj3sdxxxxxtu0lqde00.databases.appdomain.cloud:32731/bludb?security=SSL
```

Error message:

```
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
           postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
           or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
'sqlalchemy.cimmutabledict.immutabledict' object does not support item deletion
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
           postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
           or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

I am actually using this format but it just won't work.

Comment: The [README](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db-sa/) seems to suggest that your connection URL string should start with `db2+ibm_db://`

Comment: You could also try using `URL.create()` like [this](https://pastebin.com/vsK1mzCe)

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string seems malformed: instead of ending with `/bludb?security=SSL` as shown in your question, try instead using the ending below:

`/bludb;security=SSL;`

Notice the sem-colon prefix and suffix.

Works for me with SQLAlchemy 1.3.24 and ibm_db 3.1.0 and ibm_db_sa 0.3.7.
Requires that all other parts of the connection string are correct of course.

Also:  both the prefix `ibm_db_sa://....` and `db2+ibm_db://` work for me to Db2 on Cloud (lite).

Comment: Have you used db2 in flask for SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI ?

Answer (score 0):

The error stated the format is `username:password@hostname/dbname`. You will see in yours that you added the port number  So the the the change will be
`jqg6xxxx:r9C98t4TY81xxxxx@fbd88901-ebdb-4a4f-a32e-9822b9fb237b.c1ogj3sdxxxxxtu0lqde00.databases.appdomain.cloud/bludb?security=SSL`
I had the same issue recently and it worked for me.